# Error when trying to run InstaPy script on raspberry pi 4 B

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi4

I'm  trying to run script like  https://github.com/InstaPy/instapy-quickstart/blob/master/quickstart_templates/good_commenting_strategy_and_new_qs_system.py 
on my new raspbery pi 4 B 2Gb but I get a mistake, which I do not know how to solve.

I want It to work normally but instead I get this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/Sakura/Bot/daprostitnasbog.py", line 1,    in     <module>
from instapy import InstaPy
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/instapy  /__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from .instapy import InstaPy
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/instapy/instapy.py", line 28, in <module>
from .clarifai_util import check_image
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/instapy/clarifai_util.py", line 3, in <module>
from clarifai.rest import ClarifaiApp
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/clarifai/rest/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from clarifai.rest.client import ApiClient
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/clarifai/rest/client.py", line 36, in <module>
from clarifai.rest.grpc.proto.clarifai.api.endpoint_pb2_grpc import V2Stub
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/clarifai/rest/grpc/proto/clarifai/api/endpoint_pb2_grpc.py", line 2, in <module>
import grpc
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
from grpc._cython import cygrpc as _cygrpc
ImportError: /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so: undefined symbol: __atomic_exchange_8
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
pip3 install 'grpcio==1.23.0' --force-reinstall